# If statement structure in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I keep getting an error with the following bit of code. It is probably some small thing but I don't see what is wrong.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $varp = $row['ustk_retail'];
   if ($varp<80000) { $o1 = 1; }
   if (($varp=>80000) && ($varp<100000)) { $o2 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>100000) && ($varp<120000)) { $o3 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>120000) && ($varp<140000)) { $o4 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>140000) && ($varp<160000)) { $o5 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>160000) && ($varp<180000)) { $o6 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>180000) && ($varp<200000)) { $o7 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>200000) && ($varp<220000)) { $o8 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>220000) && ($varp<240000)) { $o9 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>240000) && ($varp<260000)) { $o10 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>260000) && ($varp<280000)) { $o11 = "1"; }
   if (($varp=>280000) && ($varp<300000)) { $o12 = "1"; }
   if ($varp>=300000) { $o13 = "1"; }
  }
```

Comment: specify which error did you get.

Comment: Care to post here **what** error you've got?

Comment: I get a parse error - Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-content\themes\canvas\includes\usedprice.php on line 35
Line 35  is -   if (($varp=>80000) && ($varp<100000)) { $o2 = "1"; }

Comment: You've just changed the question. That's really not helpful.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW. It's >= not =>

Comment: Ok, posing a question and then changing it completely is not helpful. Maybe you could first learn PHP syntax and then start asking questions. You could start by replacing every => into >=.

Comment: Sorry - it was the =>. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are right. It's small but hard to find mistake. Good question. See an opdate to my post. Hope it helps

Comment: Just a comment about performance.. you'd be better off using "if {} elseif{} .." .. as only one condition will ever match, there isn't any point trying every condition every time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Greater than or equal to  is `>=` sign, not `=>`

Update:
You are right. It's small but hard to find mistake.
It took me to split whole line into pieces to see where the problem is:

```
<?php
if 
(
$varp
=>
80000
)
```

So, it says parse error on line 5 and I had to doublecheck this operator.
Of course, at first I separated the problem line from the rest of the code to be certain.

Comment: Actually, if you know what the T_DOUBLE_ARROW mentioned in the error message refers to, the error is obvious and easy to find. See the linked list of parser tokens in my answer.

Answer (score 27):

Running `php -l` *(lint)* on your code I get a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

The `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` token is what PHP expects when assigning array values to array keys.

When comparing for **Greater than or equal to** the PHP Parser expects `T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL`, meaning you have to use `>=` instead of `=>`.

See

- [the chapter on Comparison Operators in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and
- [the List of Parser Tokens in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Comment: +1 and even when you are not familiar with all the tokens, `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` is a quite descriptive name. Sad that there are people who need to split their code into several lines in order to understand that. (It would be quite understandable if they got `unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` though...)

Answer (score 3):

You have an expression error.

```
$varp=>220000 // is not a valid php expression

=> operator is used to assign values in arrays like:

$x = array( 'foo' => 'bar');

>= is the comparation assigment greater than or equal
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more readable and compact way to do the same:

```
$ranges = range(300000, 80000, -20000);

$index = 1;

$varp = 220001;

foreach ($ranges as $i => $range) {
    if ($varp >= $range) {
        $index = 13 - $i;
        break;
    }
}

${'o' . $index} = 1;
```

Anyway - I think you're doing something wrong with using variable name of result.

Answer (score 2):

The answer has already been given but thought this was neat enough to share:

PHP accepts boolean expressions in it's switch statement.

```
switch(TRUE) {
    case $range <= 10:  echo "range below or equal to 10"; break;
    case $range <= 20:  echo "range above 10 below or equal to 20"; break;
    case $range <= 30:  echo "range above 20 below or equal to 30"; break;
    default: echo "high range";
}
```

In my opinion this generates the cleanest most readable code.

Comment: You probably mean `switch(true) { /* rest of your code goes here */ }`, though, right?

Comment: ah right tnx, wouldve been a nice bug for later if range ever hits "0" :)

Comment: wow, I developed in PHP for years but i never saw this use of the switch statement, it's coool ! thx ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have made a mistake in the if conditions. The greater than Equal to sign is >= and not =>.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to change `($varp=300000)` to `($varp==300000)` and it might help to enclose the full if-statement inside `()`, like this

```
if($varp80000 && $varp100000 && $varp120000 && $varp140000 && $varp160000 && $varp180000 && $varp200000 && $varp220000 && $varp240000 && $varp260000 && $varp280000 && $varp==300000) { $o13 = "1"; }
```

On another note, where to these strange $varp#### variables come from?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether the code you've posted has gotten messed up somehow, but it looks like you're missing "==" in some of the if conditions. Also, as Skilldrick pointed out, the whole if condition should be in parentheses

Answer (score 0):

"Greater than or equal to is >= NOT =>. You use => for arrays for keys/values.

Answer (score -1):

Add one more bracket around the conditions in `if`....

`if ( ($varp80000) && ($varp100000) && ($varp120000) && ($varp140000) && ($varp160000) && ($varp180000) && ($varp200000) && ($varp220000) && ($varp240000) && ($varp260000) && ($varp280000) && ($varp=300000) ) { $o13 = "1"; }`